# Exclude results that are in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am experiencing a caffeine deprivation attack...

If I have a string of numbers

```
$myStr = '100, 102, 204';
```

How do select results from mySQL db that don't have id values matching one of those in the string?

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE t1.id NOT IN ($myStr)
```

That just does not look right...

Comment: did you runt it? it looks right to me.

Comment: What "does not look right" about that to you? As long as you're ensuring that `$myStr` is always a list of numbers (i.e. preventing SQL injection) this'll be fine.

Comment: in oracle you could compose the string in a similar way to your post, then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run it dynamically.  I'm not sure if mySQL has a similar capability.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Looks fine to me.

Comment: If i understand, this will not work as you intend.  you are looking for individual ID numbers that happen to be in that string. (correct?)

Comment: @ceejayoz: The SQL `IN` clause doesn't allow a single variable to represent a list of values. The query as-is can only be run as dynamic SQL.

Comment: @OMG Ponies And? `$myStr` is a PHP variable, not an SQL one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are quoting the full clause:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE t1.id NOT IN ('100, 102, 204')
```

You need this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (100, 102, 204)
```

Comment: Yep, stupid afternoon mistakes... Caffeine... I need more caffeine. Thanks.

Comment: @santa: Next time please post your actual code. Even if that answer was correct, just from looking at the question we could just guess that you are quoting the list.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is perfectly correct.

If you just select from a single table, `id` instead of `t1.id` is enough though.

Comment: No, it's not correct because the SQL `IN` clause doesn't allow a single variable to represent a list of values.  The query as-is can only be run as dynamic SQL.

Comment: He's using PHP so he **does** use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL `IN` clause doesn't allow a single variable to represent a list of values. The query, as-is, can only be run as dynamic SQL -- on any database.

An alternative that is MySQL specific but less restricted is to use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM T1 t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.id, $myStr) = 0
```

FIND_IN_SET documentation:

> ...Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Comment: Wow, I really need to step up my mySQL skills -- there's a lot of cool things are possible.